# Calendar loses custom "open file" alerts

Tags: high-sierra, calendar

On a Mac with High Sierra 10.13.6 Calendar loses any custom alerts linked to opening a file. I tested on macOS Mojave 10.14.6 and Calendar keeps those alerts and shows them:

[image: Example of calendar event with alert to open a file]

On High Sierra, the same procedure shows no such alert and does not open the file, even after restarting Calendar. Here is the event:

[image: Example of calendar event without the alert]

Calendar also fails to display a custom alert of email, but runs it nonetheless.

In the meantime, I am running calendar alerts with Automator following [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-4082). The reason is that I want to run an AppleScript as an alert, which after Mountain Lion I would need to do by saving it as an application bundle and opening the file.

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This drove me crazy at one point too.  Make sure you are putting these events onto a local calendar, and not an iCloud calendar.  File open alerts won't work unless they are on a local "On My Mac" calendar.

Comment: Indeed, changing to a local calendar "On My Mac" enables opening a file. Thanks for driving me back to sanity!